# How to combine RNN with CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a program that subtracts using two images from MNIST. In doing so, we are using an algorithm that combines CNN and RNN.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amRuz.jpg)

```
class CRNN_Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CRNN_Model, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = 256
        self.batch_size = 128
        self.sequence_size = 2
        self.output_size = 19
        self.img_size = 28

        #cnn
        self.reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1))
        self.maxpooling1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')
        self.maxpooling2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()
        self.flatten1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.hidden_size, activation='relu')
        #rnn
        self.rnn_cell = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(self.hidden_size, activation=None)

    def call(self, x):
        #cnn
        hidden_list = []
        for i in range(2):
            x = x[0][i]        
            x = self.conv1(x)
            x = self.maxpooling1(x)
            x = self.conv2(x)
            x = self.maxpooling2(x)
            x = self.flatten1(x)
            x = self.hidden(x)

            hidden_list.append(x)

        self.hidden_list = tf.transpose(hidden_list, perm=[1, 0, 2])

        #rnn
        self.initial_state = self.rnn_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf_float32)
        state = self.initial_state
        outputs = []
        for t in range(self.sequence_size):
            (output, state) = self.rnn_cell(self.hidden_list[:, t, :], state)
            outputs.append(output)
        self.outputs = outputs
 
        self.prediction = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.outputs[-1], self.output_size)
        self.pred_output = tf.keras.activations.softmax(self.prediction)

        return self.pred_output
```

However, an error occurs at the input to the first conv1 layer.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_111 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (28, 28, 1)
```

The shape of the data we are giving is as follows.

```
print(np.shape(train_x))
print(np.shape(train_y))
print(np.shape(test_x))
print(np.shape(test_y))

(10000, 2, 28, 28, 1)
         →(number of data * number of image * width * height * channel)
(10000, 1)
(2000, 2, 28, 28, 1)
(2000, 1)
```

How do I give the data?

Comment: you want to change the variable `input` to something else since `input` already exists in python. Also why not just classify the two images  separately and subtract their output

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote ```input``` to ```x``` and ran the code. However, the same error occurs.
Also, I am planning to apply it to a task that is not recognized by MNIST in the future, so I purposely designed it this way.